# Azure Portal - Create Document Failed - Entity with the specified id already exists in the system

Tags: azure, azureportal

I am getting this when trying to create a new document in a cosmos DB container.
No, the Id definitely does not already exist but I'm still unable to save the new file created for the first time. Getting this ever so often, then appears to sort itself out, but it's really frustrating because can't save new documents when need to.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to resolve?

Have tried several different unique names, refreshing, using a new tab, clearing the browser cache etc. anything else to try?

Full error message from popup below;

**Create document failed**

*Entity with the specified id already exists in the system., RequestStartTime: 2023-02-15T17:15:23.7571693Z, RequestEndTime: 2023-02-15T17:15:23.7571693Z, Number of regions attempted:1 {"systemHistory":[{"dateUtc":"2023-02-15T17:14:20.3055487Z","cpu":0.537,"memory":494453100.000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0377,"availableThreads":32763,"minThreads":52,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":506},{"dateUtc":"2023-02-15T17:14:30.3157513Z","cpu":1.468,"memory":495121388.000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0246,"availableThreads":32762,"minThreads":52,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":506},{"dateUtc":"2023-02-15T17:14:40.3260707Z","cpu":0.472,"memory":495105576.000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0132,"availableThreads":32764,"minThreads":52,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":505},{"dateUtc":"2023-02-15T17:14:50.3363254Z","cpu":0.555,"memory":495019484.000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0282,"availableThreads":32764,"minThreads":52,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":505},{"dateUtc":"2023-02-15T17:15:00.3467551Z","cpu":1.111,"memory":495027292.000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0255,"availableThreads":32763,"minThreads":52,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":505},{"dateUtc":"2023-02-15T17:15:10.3568375Z","cpu":0.559,"memory":495008380.000,"threadInfo":{"isThreadStarving":"False","threadWaitIntervalInMs":0.0155,"availableThreads":32764,"minThreads":52,"maxThreads":32767},"numberOfOpenTcpConnection":503}]} RequestStart: 2023-02-15T17:15:23.7571693Z; ResponseTime: 2023-02-15T17:15:23.7571693Z; StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.0.0.34:14300/apps/c8ad9db4-cea9-48d8-9f4c-a680fc37edf0/services/277b4e29-80c4-4118-8a5e-a57346d6ef1e/partitions/45292f34-171b-40b8-8a5d-40996adabfdf/replicas/133201146384367926p, LSN: 2061, GlobalCommittedLsn: 2061, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 409, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1.24, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#2061, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, BELatencyMs: 1.63, ActivityId: 3f54660b-6e43-4b71-9a36-125fdb5565d8, RetryAfterInMs: , TransportRequestTimeline: {"requestTimeline":[{"event": "Created", "startTimeUtc": "2023-02-15T17:15:23.7571693Z", "durationInMs": 0.0115},{"event": "ChannelAcquisitionStarted", "startTimeUtc": "2023-02-15T17:15:23.7571808Z", "durationInMs": 0.0141},{"event": "Pipelined", "startTimeUtc": "2023-02-15T17:15:23.7571949Z", "durationInMs": 0.2096},{"event": "Transit Time", "startTimeUtc": "2023-02-15T17:15:23.7574045Z", "durationInMs": 2.1625},{"event": "Received", "startTimeUtc": "2023-02-15T17:15:23.7595670Z", "durationInMs": 0.1415},{"event": "Completed", "startTimeUtc": "2023-02-15T17:15:23.7597085Z", "durationInMs": 0}],"serviceEndpointStats":{"inflightRequests":1,"openConnections":1},"connectionStats":{"waitforConnectionInit":"False","callsPendingReceive":0,"lastSendAttempt":"2023-02-15T17:14:29.9557540Z","lastSend":"2023-02-15T17:14:29.9557540Z","lastReceive":"2023-02-15T17:14:29.9557540Z"},"requestSizeInBytes":1250,"requestBodySizeInBytes":718,"responseMetadataSizeInBytes":179,"responseBodySizeInBytes":49}; ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Create , Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0*

Answer (score 0):

> Entity with the specified id already exists in the system:

***This is usually the case if the specified name already exists in the same or another region.***

*Other possible reasons for this occurrence include:*

- When a document is created in a `Cosmos DB` container, it is first sent to the database and then indexed. If there is an interruption in the indexing process, the document may not be available for querying. Then it displays these types of errors.
- Keep checking the id name you provide multiple times to see if it exists within the `Cosmos container` or any other containers, as it supports unique names for all Azure resources.
- As stated in this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-not-found#invalid-character-in-an-item-id), Check for the `Cosmos DB SDK` compatibility with your code and check any invalid characters existed in your ID.

When I created in my environment, I also got the same error for container itself stating that ID already exists. Then I changed the region from `WestUs` to `EastUs` and then it worked.

[image]

[image]

Reference: [Article](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/dp-420-cosmos-db-dev/instructions/26-sdk-troubleshoot.html)